# Android: TabLayout adentro de otro TabLayout (Conflictos)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo un Tablayout que tiene los fragmentos de Menu, Entrada, Platillo Fuerte, Postre y Bebida , los cuales tienen un Recyclerview y Viewpager que se llena con las respectivas comidas, despues metí todo en un Activity que tiene otro TabLayout y Viewpager con el proposito de pedir la comida para varios clientes, los clientes podran irse agregando dinamicamente , ahora , el problema viene que para cada cliente , utilizo el mismo fragmento , al llamar el mismo fragmento , funciona , pero no se llena el Viewpager con sus respectivos fragmentos, ademas , si deslizo a la derecha o izquierda, no se desliza bien, queda a la mitad y se mueve muy lento.

¿Alguna solución?

Aqui el codigo :

Activity Detalle Restaurante XML

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.eduardoricardez.restominute.RestaurantDetalle">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivRestaurant"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom = "true" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/BlackTransparent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="8dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical">

                        <com.thebrownarrow.customfont.CustomFontTextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvRestaurantName"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            android:text="Restaurant"
                            app:custom_typeface="fonts/estandar.ttf" />

                        <com.thebrownarrow.customfont.CustomFontTextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvRestaurantAddress"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
                            android:textSize="14sp"
                            android:text="Adresse"
                            app:custom_typeface="fonts/light.ttf" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp">

                        <com.thebrownarrow.customfont.CustomFontTextView
                            android:layout_width="40dp"
                            android:layout_height="40dp"
                            android:text="-10%"
                            android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
                            android:textSize="12sp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            app:custom_typeface="fonts/light.ttf"
                            android:background="@drawable/promotion"
                            android:elevation="2dp" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_NavigationTabStrip"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="#CB1515"
            android:paddingEnd="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:paddingStart="20dp">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/ntsClient"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                app:tabTextColor="#81ffffff"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="#fff"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp">

            </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

            <!--
            <com.gigamole.navigationtabstrip.NavigationTabStrip
                android:id="@+id/ntsMealsClient"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                app:nts_active_color="#fff"
                app:nts_inactive_color="#81ffffff"
                app:nts_titles="@array/restaurantClient"
                app:nts_typeface="fonts/light.ttf"
                app:nts_weight="0dp"
                app:nts_size="12sp" />
            -->
        </FrameLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/containerMealsClient"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center">

            <com.thebrownarrow.customfont.CustomFontButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Ajouter un client"
                android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
                android:background="@drawable/button_precommander"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                app:custom_typeface="fonts/estandar.ttf"
                android:onClick="agregarCliente" />

            <com.thebrownarrow.customfont.CustomFontButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Retirer un client"
                android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
                android:background="@drawable/button_precommander"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                app:custom_typeface="fonts/estandar.ttf"
                android:onClick="retirarCliente" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/transparent_banner" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/bouton_panier"
                    android:onClick="AbrirCarrito" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Fragmento restaurant_client_fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_NavigationTabStrip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="#CB1515"
        android:paddingEnd="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingStart="20dp">

        <com.gigamole.navigationtabstrip.NavigationTabStrip
            android:id="@+id/ntsMeals"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:nts_active_color="#fff"
            app:nts_color="#fff"
            app:nts_factor="2.8"
            app:nts_corners_radius="1.5dp"
            app:nts_inactive_color="#81ffffff"
            app:nts_titles="@array/restaurant"
            app:nts_typeface="fonts/light.ttf"
            app:nts_weight="3dp"
            app:nts_size="12sp" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/containerMeals"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</LinearLayout>
```

row_meals_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="20dp">

                <com.thebrownarrow.customfont.CustomFontTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvMealTitulo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Menu 1"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    app:custom_typeface="fonts/estandar.ttf" />

                <com.thebrownarrow.customfont.CustomFontTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvMealPrecio"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="15.50 €"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    app:custom_typeface="fonts/light.ttf" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center">

                <com.thebrownarrow.customfont.CustomFontTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvMealDescripcion"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Description"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    app:custom_typeface="fonts/estandar.ttf"
                    android:textAlignment="center" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Los java

RestaurantDetalle.java

```
public class RestaurantDetalle extends AppCompatActivity {
    CustomFontTextView tvRestaurantName;
    CustomFontTextView tvRestaurantAddress;
    ImageView ivRestaurant;

    ViewPager mViewPager;
    //NavigationTabStrip tabLayout;
    TabLayout tabLayout;

    //Tabs
    private ClientePageAdapter mClientePageAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.restaurant_fragment);

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        tvRestaurantName = (CustomFontTextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRestaurantName);
        tvRestaurantAddress = (CustomFontTextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRestaurantAddress);
        ivRestaurant = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivRestaurant);

        Picasso.with(this)
                .load("https://restominute-dev.herokuapp.com/upload/" + intent.getStringExtra("restaurantId") + "?token=FYfZ%2Fo28Mva6MGYnFOdiSOPPdVwSbTuYd86P3wYlq%2Fb5CDqHJwUgQKX5aALSiBP4XQC3TswG8I37%2F4K62ZUnx11n3MIc7sckbDCs8kFbbDMbuql8p0chLLHV20FLu90DfyCSkSvP9D2NAHgNAF8jk76%2B717S2qo%2F7XCw7QQtxIc%3D")
                .resize(350, 300)
                .placeholder(R.color.colorAccent)
                .into(ivRestaurant);

        tvRestaurantName.setText(intent.getStringExtra("restaurantName"));
        tvRestaurantAddress.setText(intent.getStringExtra("restaurantAddress"));
        Meal.setRestaurantID(intent.getStringExtra("restaurantId"));

        // TABS Y VIEWPAGER
        mClientePageAdapter = new ClientePageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        //tabLayout = (NavigationTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.ntsMealsClient);
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.containerMealsClient);
        setupViewPager(mViewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.ntsClient);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewpager) {
        mClientePageAdapter.addFragment(new TabMealsClientFragment(), "Cliente 1");
        mClientePageAdapter.addFragment(new TabMealsClientFragment(), "Cliente 2");
        viewpager.setAdapter(mClientePageAdapter);
    }

    private void addTab(String title) {
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(title));
        mClientePageAdapter.addTabPage(title);
    }

    public void AbrirCarrito(View view) {
        Intent PanierIntent = new Intent(this, PanierActivity.class);
        this.startActivity(PanierIntent);
    }
}
```

TabsMealsClientFragment.java

```
public class TabMealsClientFragment extends Fragment {
    ViewPager mViewPager;
    NavigationTabStrip tabLayout;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.restaurant_client_fragment, container, false); //Set up the viewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.containerMeals);

        SectionsPageAdapter adapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        tabLayout = (NavigationTabStrip) view.findViewById(R.id.ntsMeals);
        tabLayout.setViewPager(mViewPager);

        return view;
    }
}
```

Adapters

```
public class ClientePageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addTabPage(String title) {
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    public ClientePageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }
}

public class SectionsPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList= new ArrayList<>();

    public SectionsPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);

        mFragmentList.add(new TabMenuFragment());
        mFragmentList.add(new TabEntreeFragment());
        mFragmentList.add(new TabPlatFragment());
        mFragmentList.add(new TabDessertFragment());
        mFragmentList.add(new TabBoissonFragment());
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo solucioné con `getChildFragmentManager` en el segundo Tab

```
SectionsPageAdapter adapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
```

Comment: Hola Eduardo, me resulta un poco extraño usar dos TabLayout, luego nos compartes tu aplicación para revisar la usabilidad como curiosidad, saludos.

Comment: @Jorgesys Claro, la funcionalidad es que hay 2 botones, agregar cliente y eliminar cliente, asi puedes seleccionar la comida para clientes diferentes. Si son 2 que van a comer , agregas 2 clientes y su respectiva comida para cada 1. Ya lo compartire ahora que lo termine.

Comment: Muchas gracias Eduardo, saludos! :)